# Incorrect updating of TextView gravity

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a simple application, and once you press a button a `TextView` that is contained in a `HorizontalScrollView` is updated. I want this `TextView` to be horizontally centered, and when the text expands to be scrollable horizontally as it is too long, I have to switch the `TextView` to a gravity of left, otherwise the `ScrollView` behaves incorrectly and cuts off the text at the beginning and there is a lot of blank space at the end. Here is my current code to handle this:

```
//make horizontal scroll text center and work
final HorizontalScrollView toTextScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.horizScroll);
final TextView toNumber = (TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.toField);

toTextScrollView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top,
            int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
            int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        //if scrollable, change toNumber layout_gravity to left, else keep it at center
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if(canScroll(toTextScrollView))
        {
            params.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can scroll", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot scroll", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        toNumber.setLayoutParams(params);

    }

});
```

This code *mostly* works. My `canScroll()` function works correctly as it updates the `Toast` correctly when it can and cannot scroll. Also, the gravity does change to Left whenever the `ScrollView` is scrollable, and to Center when it is not. *However*, it does this one "change" late. As in whenever the view becomes scrollable, the `Toast` reports "scrollable" but does not change the Gravity of the `TextView` to Left until another number is added. Also, if the view is scrollable and becomes unscrollable, the `Toast` correctly says this, but the `TextView` is kept at Left gravity, but if another number is removed, meaning it is still unscrollable, then it correctly updates to center gravity.

Comment: What happens if you just set the TextView property 'android:scrollbars="horizontal"' instead of trying to embed it in the HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: I can't add scrollbars to a non-scrollable container.